# Is it possible to create a bootable usb from a partition?

Tags: linux, boot, usb-drive, cloning

Is it possible? How hard would it be to do so?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean.  Do you want to take a partition on your machine and transfer it to a USB stick?

Comment: Yes, and then use it to boot on another machine

Comment: Look around the [tag:cloning] tag for similar questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It is not very hard but it requires a good comprehension of *boot sequence*.

The "copy" sequence is something like:

1. partition you usb stick and mkfs the partitions.
2. copy the files from source partitions to usb-stick partitions (e.g. using `rsync`).
3. modify the `/etc/fstab` to match your new partitions.
4. install a new boot-loader on usb-stick.

The last point is the hard one. You are copying a full-fledged linux system on the stick so you can't use vfat partitions. If you use ext2 partitions, you'll can use [syslinux](http://www.syslinux.org) otherwise you'll have to use [grub](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/).

In any case, the result will be very slow because *normal* distributions are not optimized for this kind of use. If you do not need a temporary solution, try some live distribution. For example, it is very simple to create a customized [system rescue cd](http://www.sysresccd.org) usb-stick adding whatever software you need on it.

A little hint: use `UUIDs` to identify partitions because it is the only way to be sure that partition identifiers do not change if you change host or plug-in another usb device.

Comment: This looks kinda fun. When copying files over, do I need to copy the Device and Special files?